# Is there any effect of gravity in a vertical nonlinear spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, spring, non-linear-systems

I know that for a linear vertical spring, the governing equation of motion written in the presence of gravity is the same as the one written in the absence of gravity. We can either undergo a transformation or cancel the terms while balancing the laws using the free-body diagram.

What about nonlinear springs?

Please let me know the possible explanations.

Comment: The restoring force provided by a spring as a function of the change in length of the spring is a property of only the spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a vertical nonlinear spring, the effect of gravity can indeed influence the behavior of the spring and the motion of an object attached to it. Unlike a linear spring, where the relationship between force and displacement is linear, nonlinear springs have force-displacement relationships that are nonlinear, meaning the force applied by the spring is not directly proportional to the displacement from the equilibrium position.

The behavior of a nonlinear spring under the influence of gravity can vary depending on the specific form of the spring's force-displacement relationship.

If we have a "Non-linear" Spring with Increasing Stiffness (ergo, [Hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)-ean spring with a quadratic term): In some cases, a nonlinear spring becomes stiffer as it is compressed or stretched. This behavior is often seen in springs with quadratic or higher-order terms in their force-displacement equations. When an object is attached to such a spring and placed in a gravitational field, the weight of the object adds to the forces acting on the spring. As the object moves away from the equilibrium position, the spring force increases nonlinearly, and this increased force due to both the spring's nonlinearity and gravity can lead to complex oscillatory behavior or even chaotic motion.

But this is not the case in certain Nonlinear Springs with Decreasing Stiffness. Some nonlinear springs become less stiff as they are compressed or stretched. In this case, the gravitational force can also interact with the spring's nonlinearity. Depending on the specific form of the spring's force-displacement relationship and the orientation of the spring, the object attached to it may exhibit unusual behaviors, such as bouncing or undergoing irregular oscillations.

To analyze the motion of an object attached to a nonlinear spring in the presence of gravity, you would typically use Newton's second law, taking into account the forces acting on the object. This would include the spring force (which depends on the displacement from equilibrium and the spring's nonlinearity), the gravitational force, and any other external forces. The resulting equation of motion is a differential equation that may not have a simple closed-form solution and may require numerical methods for analysis.

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand how gravity would different on a non-linear spring.Doesnt gravity exist without the existence of the non-linear spring?.But some very interesting effects may take place for example the spring may not have a stable condition , it may have 2 astable conditions.